# Prove that if $x_n \rightarrow L$ then $-x_n \rightarrow -L$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

The right arrow is saying $x_n$ converges to L

Definition of convergence in book: For a sequence x of real numbers and a real number L, we say x has limit L(or x converges to L) iff for every $\epsilon$ > 0 there exists a natural number N such that if n>N, then |$x_n - L$| < $\epsilon$.

($\forall \epsilon > 0$)($∃N \in \mathbb N$)($\forall n \in \mathbb N$)($n>N$ $\implies |x_n - L| < \epsilon$)

$|-x_n-(-L)|<\epsilon$

$|-x_n+L|<\epsilon$

$-x_n+L<\epsilon$

edit:

pf. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Pick n $\in \mathbb N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$. So, $|-(x_n-L)|$ =$|(-x_n)-(-L)| < \epsilon$ for all n>N.

Comment: Why do you introduce $y_n\to M?$

Comment: @mfl sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
|x_n-L|=|-(x_n-L)|=|(-x_n)-(-L)|.
$$

Comment: Oh ok, can you give me feedback on the proof I wrote?

Comment: What you wrote after 'pf.' is in the right direction, but what you're trying to bound is $|(-x_n)-(-L)|$ so the way to finish your proof would be "So, $|(-x_n)-(-L)|=|-(x_n-L)|=|x_n-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$."

Comment: Ok, I went the wrong way. Thanks for the help.